не работает функция map на Пайтоне
Решаю задачи на Python, ввел код для одной из них и при тесте выдало ошибку, оказывается у меня не работает ф-я map. Вот код:
n, m = (int(i) for i in input().split())

sp = map(int, input().split()[:m])

print(sp)

m это кол-во элементов в списке, я решил понять что не так, и попытался вывести список после применения map, выводит следующее: <map object at 0x7fde37e4afa0>

функция map работает

тогда что не так с моим кодом? Почему список не выводится после этой функции?

Функция map - генератор по нему можно пройтись циклом, но нельзя получить отдельный элемент, чтобы превратить его в список можно использовать функцию list: list(map(int, input().split()[:m]))

спасибо большое, теперь до меня дошло

Много времени сэкономил, написав фя вместо функция?
